# Ajax travando troca de página (LongPolling)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, navegador-de-internet

Estou tentando concluir uma conexão utilizando Long Polling, onde o navegador envia uma solicitação ao servidor e ficar aguardando uma resposta.
Para evitar que essa porta fique infinitamente aberta, criei uma rotina para que a cada 10 segundos o servidor envie uma resposta vazia ao navegador, informando que não houve nada até o momento.

Esta tudo funcionando perfeitamente, não tive nenhum problema relacionado a isso.

Meu problema é que quando o usuário clica em algum link da página, o navegador espera a resposta da chamada para poder atualizar, ou seja, pode levar até 10 seg. Isso faz com que pareça que a ferramenta é lenta.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

[image: exemplo do longpolling funcionando]
[image: o que acontece quando clico em um link]

Segue a função JavaScript usada para fazer a chamada:

```
function loadJSON() {

    if(libera) {

        var data_file = http + "bibliotecas/longpolling/notificacoes.php";

        var data = {};
            data.n = long_n;
            data.u = userchat;
            data.m = msgchat;
            data.c = chatUsuario;

        http_request.onreadystatechange  = function() {

            if(http_request.readyState == 4 && http_request.status == 200) {

                try {
                    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
                    var qtd = jsonObj.funcao.length;
                    if(qtd > 0) {
                        var funcao = "";
                        for(var key in jsonObj.funcao) {
                            funcao = jsonObj.funcao[key];
                            MontarFuncao(eval(funcao),jsonObj.metodo[key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {
                    //alert('Erro - '+ http_request.responseText);
                }

                loadJSON();
            }
        }

        var string = JSON.stringify(data);

        http_request.open("POST", data_file, true);
        http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", string.length);
        http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        http_request.send(string);  

        return;
    }
}
```

Segue a função PHP responsável por ficar aberta esperando alguma alteração no banco de dados:

```
ob_start();
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents(`php://input`));

while($x < 5) {

    if(time() >= (15 + $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) || connection_aborted()) {
        echo str_pad(NULL,1);
        die(json_encode(array()));
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        break;
    }

    //Funções de consulta ao BD (Se houver algo adiciona Array no variavel $retorno)

    if(count($retorno) > 0) {
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit;           
    }
    else {
        flush();
        sleep(2);
        $x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: É possivel mostrar informação parcial? ou toda a informação necessária vem du uma só vez? imagino que tenha um `.png` ou `.gif` ou mensagem a dizer que está a acontecer algo no *background*. Se não tiver, isso é importante para o utilizador saber que a página está a tratar do pedido.

Comment: Pode-nos mostrar sua chamada ajax?

Comment: Quando vc abri a ligaçao com o servidor usando xmlhttp.open, vc usa Async TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: Você poderia usar o SignalR com ASP.Net

Comment: Adicionei o código usado para facilitar. Obrigado pela ajuda de todos até o momento.

Answer (score 1):

Sem observar a forma que você está enviando ficamos meio no escuro, mas você pode utilizar o método $.ajax do JQuery definindo o **async** como TRUE ou FALSE dependendo da necessidade, TRUE = assíncrona e FALSE = NÃO assíncrona.

Eu faria mais ou menos assim:

> *não realizei testes no código, mas acho que deve funcionar...*

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    setInterval(function(){rServer('',true)},10000);

    $('.link').click(function(){
        clearInterval(rServer);
        var notificacoes = {n:3, u:'alguma coisa'};
        rServer(vars,false);
        setInterval(function(){rServer('',true)},10000);
    });
});

function rServer(vars,asyncStatus){
    $.ajax({
        url: script.php, // url do seu script
        type: "POST",// método HTTP utilizado
        data: vars, // parâmetros que serão enviados, no seu exemplo {n:3,u=''}
        dataType: "Json", // forma de recebimento da resposta
        async: asyncStatus
    }).done(function(data) {
        // **data** devolve as repostas do servidor
        // ação depois da reposta do servidor
    });
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou postar meu código, porém não utilizo JQuery.